Periodic Bessel potential space. Embedding with continuous functions.
Let $1<p<\infty$. The Bessel potencial space is $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n):=\left\{u\text{ tempered distribution }\colon \left\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\widehat{u}(\xi)\right)\right\|_{p}<\infty\right\}$. If $s>n/p$, then any function $u\in H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is continuous and bounded.
Question. Is it true in the periodic Bessel potencial space?
The periodic Bessel potencial space is $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{T}^n):=\left\{u\text{ periodic distribution }\colon \left\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((1+|k|^2)^{s/2}\widehat{u}(k)\right)\right\|_{p}<\infty\right\}$. Here, the Fourier transform is the periodic or Toroidal Fourier transform.
I only found the case $p=2$ in M.E. Taylor, Partial Differential Equations I: Basic Theory (Springer New York, New York, NY, 2011 (Proposition 3.3, (3.4)), i.e.,
If $H^{s}(M)$ with $M$ a smooth compact manifold of dimension $n$ then $u$ is continuous on $M$ when $s>n/2$, but, I can't find for a general $p$.
Thanks.

Yes, this is still true. You can find it for example in "Topics in Fourier Analysis and Function Spaces" by Hans-Jürgen Schmeisser and Hans Triebel, Chichester [u.a: Wiley. (1987).
In Chapter 3.5.4 they introduce a whole bunch of periodic spaces, including $H^{s,p}(\mathbb T^n)$ and in Chapter 3.5.5 there are some embedding theorems, one of which is
$$F^{s+ \frac np}_{p,q}(\mathbb T^n) \subset \mathscr C^s(\mathbb T^n).$$
This is exactly what you want because the Zygmund spaces $\mathscr C^s$ coincide with Hölder spaces if $s$ is not an integer and for $q=2$ the left hand side is exactly the Bessel-potential space $H^{s+ \frac np, p}$.

oh thanks. Then if $s+n/p<r$ we have that $H^{r,p}(T^n)\subset H^{s+n/p}(T^n)$. Therefore $H^{r,p}(T^n)\subset \mathscr{C}^{s}(T^n)$

But with $s=1$, $\text{Zygmund}(s)\neq \text{Holder}(s)$?
